# Is there a way to parse data from mixed xml tag using DOM4J in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

Suppose this is the XML.

```
<A>

 <A1> 123 </A1>
 <A2> 234 </A2>
 asdfgh
</A>
<B>
 asdfgh
</B>
```

I need only contents of A and B not their sub tags.

Comment: There is a way. Have you found out how to get access to the `A` or `B` tag?

Comment: @f1sh Yes by using new Node().getParent()

Comment: Shouldn't `theNodeOfA.getText()` return the value you are looking for?

Comment: Its not happening buddy

Comment: Then maybe it would be worth to provide an example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are currently using for others to be able to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is not valid xml.Specially the value inside tag A.If you have a case like tag A in that case you need to add one more tag inside A named as .Something like below.

```
<A>

 <A1> 123 </A1>
 <A2> 234 </A2>
 <value>asdfgh</value>
</A>
<B>
 asdfgh
</B>
```

Comment: The requirement is clear, it's about parsing the document. "Change what you want to parse" is not an answer.

Comment: Actually Mr.Krutik that kind of XML tags are called mixed tags. And I want a way to extract that content in java using DOM4J